# Firefox: External 3rd party tool for cleaning unmanageable bookmark-collection?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have an extremely large bookmark collection due to a past unfortunate habit of bookmarking all tabs. Much of this collection consists of bookmarked viral media pages, youtube, assorted funnies etc and of course there are extremely many duplicates. I'd like to get rid of some of these. Unfortunately, firefox freezes and eventually crashes whenever I attempt to search and delete any large group of bookmarks. I have tried exporting my bookmarks to Chrome in order to use a Chrome extension for removing duplicates, but, although that extension managed to find an embarrassing 25k duplicates, it failed to delete them.

So my question is this: are there any modern third-party bookmark management tools that can help me clean out my bookmarks in a simple and easy way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me the Firefox Plugin: [bookmark deduplicator](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/bookmark-deduplicator/?src=search) did a good job.

But as always, make a backup before using a software that delete things.